# Problems determining my voice type, fach, passagio

Tags: vocal-range

I have problems determining my voice type. I have serious problems singing lower than A2 although I can reach F2#, but my second passagio is around E4 to F#4 so I have no clue what kind of voice type I have. I dont know I am Bass/Baritone/Tenor, because my lower range is strong(my speaking voice is A2 to C3) but uncomfortable to sing in, but upper range is very light and agile. In falsetto I go up to A5 and my head voice is strong but it is hard to sing in head voice lower than G4. Please help?!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter.  Singing teachers are not specialized so thoroughly that you need that information for choosing a teacher, a choir conductor would not let *you* decide which voice to sing, and any soloist ambitions would depend on having a suitably trained voice *first*.

So just go ahead with your road to singing and save your decisions until you actually arrive at a fork in the road.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell for sure without hearing you, but it sounds like you're probably a baritone with a good head voice.  Falsetto doesn't factor into this determination, and in fact the lowest voices often have the highest falsetto ranges.  Also for the record, the fach system is only used in the professional opera setting and is close to meaningless anywhere else.